Is there a difference in using Google Sheets on Android or Apple?
My problem is, that I created a Google Sheets File for sharing it with a link so that everybody else can work with it, too.
If I'm sending the link with an android smartphone, the link contains the word "sheets" and the file is accessable for everybody, no matter if they have android or apple.
But if I'm sending the link with an apple smartphone, the link contains the word "file" instead of "sheets" so that the file doesn't open in Google Sheets but in a browser where it's not accessable to change anything in it.
And yes, I created the link in Google Sheets the same way on android as on apple - the link is all the same but the word "sheets" and "file".
Is this an apple problem? Or how can I change it, that it's automatically an "sheets-link" allthough created in apple?
I tried to create the link in android and in apple, even on more smartphones to be sure that it's not a problem with just one phone.

Please edit the question to 1) describe how the link was created, 2) include the original link (replace the ID with 'X''s), and 3) include the android link AND the iPhone link.
